# How to determine which component triggers the event handler in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to bind a event handler to multiple components in React. Now I set `className` to every component and use `event.currentTarget.className` to determine which component triggers the handler.

```
handleClick: function (e) {
    var className = e.currentTarget.className;
    if (className === "longComment") {
        this.setState({showLongComment: !this.state.showLongComment});
    } else {
        this.setState({showShortComment: !this.state.showShortComment});
    }
},

render: function () {
    var topic = this.props.topic;
    var shortComment = this.state.showShortComment ? '[-]' : '[+]';
    var longComment = this.state.showLongComment ? '[--]' : '[++]';

    return (
        <li className="topic">
            <div className="title">
                <a target="_blank" href={api}>
                    {this.props.children.toString()}
                </a>&nbsp;
                <span className="longComment" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    {longcomment}
                </span>
                <span className="shortComment" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    {shortcomment}
                </span>
            </div>
            {this.state.showLongComment ? <CommentList url={url} /> : null}
            {this.state.showShortComment ? <CommentList url={url} /> : null}
        </li>
    );
}
```

Is there any native way in React to know which component triggers the event handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by binding different parameters to `handleClick` functions:

```
handleClick: function (propertyName) {

    var newState = {};
    newState[propertyName] = !this.state[propertyName];
    this.setState(newState);

},

render: function () {
    var topic = this.props.topic;
    var shortComment = this.state.showShortComment ? '[-]' : '[+]';
    var longComment = this.state.showLongComment ? '[--]' : '[++]';

    return (
        <li className="topic">
            <div className="title">
                <a target="_blank" href={api}>
                    {this.props.children.toString()}
                </a>&nbsp;
                <span className="longComment" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,"showLongComment")}>
                    {longcomment}
                </span>
                <span className="shortComment" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,"showShortComment")}>
                    {shortcomment}
                </span>
            </div>
            {this.state.showLongComment ? <CommentList url={url} /> : null}
            {this.state.showShortComment ? <CommentList url={url} /> : null}
        </li>
    );
}
```

Comment: Such a clean solution. I didn't thought I can avoid the if clause. Thank you!

Comment: Not ideal though as your functions will get re-created for every render. You can use `ev.currentTarget` as an alternative way to find the source item.