# How to distinguish callback from multiple component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made two `Slider` class like this

```
    <Slider
      sliderNum="0"
      min={0} max={1} step={0.1}
      orientation="vertical"
      defaultValue={0.8}
      aria-labelledby="vertical-slider"
      onChange={this.handleVoSliderChange}
    /> 
   <Slider
      sliderNum="1"
      min={0} max={1} step={0.1}
      orientation="vertical"
      defaultValue={0.8}
      aria-labelledby="vertical-slider"
      onChange={this.handleVoSliderChange}
    />
```

then, in callback, how can check which is which ??

```
handleVoSliderChange(event,value){
  console.log(event);
}
```

I am checking the event but it looks like mouse event.

and value also doesn't work for this purpose.

Comment: Is this the Material slider??

Comment: How about adding two handlers, like `onChange={this.handleVoSliderChange1}` and `onChange={this.handleVoSliderChange2}` and define two handlers separately? Or if you prefer, can write a handler wrapper and call with different component ID in the wrapper, but if there are only two components I think the former one is ok

Comment: does it have event.target or event.srcElement? Inspect the event object. console.log is your friend.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252703/how-to-determine-which-component-triggers-the-event-handler-in-react

Comment: If you have your method take a number and return a function to do whatever it's doing, you could avoid needing to mess with synthetic events. `handleVoSliderChange (whichSlider) { return (event, value) => { }}`, used with `onChange={handleVoSliderChange(1)}` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `sliderNum` parameter to your handler.

```js
handleVoSliderChange(event, value, sliderNum){
  console.log(sliderNum);
  // ...
}
```

```js
<>
  <Slider
    sliderNum="0"
    onChange={(event, value) => this.handleVoSliderChange(event, value, 0)}
  />
  <Slider
    sliderNum="1"
    onChange={(event, value) => this.handleVoSliderChange(event, value, 1)}
  />
</>
```

Comment: wow simply problem solved thank you very much.